# Simple subclass template pattern

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

I have some `Base` class with a virtual method `foo()`. I need to generate several subclasses that are all identical in structure and simply override `foo()` in different ways. I came up with this simple non-type argument template:

```
template<const int Index>
class Derived : public Base
{
  virtual void foo() {....};
};



typedef Derived<1> Derived_1;
typedef Derived<2> Derived_2;
...
...
```

and then method `foo` is specialised for each case.

I am not completely satisfied with this strategy because you need to be careful with index collisions (although that's no such big deal) and the implementation file loses readability as you need to know what index '2' or '3' corresponds to. It would be better to use a string

```
typedef Derived<"Derived_2"> Derived_2;
```

but string literals are not allowed as template arguments.

Is this a recommended pattern to use in this case? Anything better? (Maybe this is a known pattern that has even a name, but I don't know what to look for.)

Comment: How about using an enum, the members of which you can name ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for the template argument. Why not just create `Derived_1` and `Derived_2` classes and override `foo`?

Comment: @TartanLlama Simply to save lines of code. Suppose derived classes need to implement a number of identical constructors/operators... the size of the code will blow up.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon Then why not write `class SpecialDerived1 :  public Derived` and override `foo` in there?

Comment: @TartanLlama Not sure I'm following, how would that change the scenario?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon you'd just put all the constructors and operators in `Derived` and inherit them at the next level of inheritance. Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b007721a32e951aa).

Comment: @TartanLlama Ok, now I see what you mean. That's another good option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an enum as the template parameter:

```
enum class type {foo, bar};

template<type name>
class Derived //...
{};

typedef Derived<type::foo> Derived_foo;
```

Comment: Probably better with specification of the values : `type {foo = 1, bar = 2}`. It increases the readability, in this case.

Comment: @Caduchon if the enum is simply used as a list of names and only compared for equality, then in my opnion, giving them explicit values reduces readability.

Comment: I'm like this one due to my allergy to macros.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like modelling this relationship with inheritance is closer to the semantics you are trying to achieve.

```
struct Derived1 : Derived
{
  using Derived::Derived; 
  virtual void foo() {
      std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;
  };
};

struct Derived2 : Derived
{
  using Derived::Derived;
  virtual void foo() {
      std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
  };
};
```

With this version you can happily use any of the `DerivedN` versions as `Derived` objects, so converting between them or operating on different versions together is easier than having all of your cross-derived member functions as templates.

The `using Derived::Derived;` declarations are needed to inherit any non-default constructors which `Derived` might have.

Comment: Could you clarify the role of 'using Derived::Derived;'?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more clear with pre-processor definition :

```
#define DERIVED1 1
#define DERIVED2 2
typedef Derived<DERIVED1> Derived_1;
typedef Derived<DERIVED2> Derived_2;
```

Or maybe with enum ? (I'm not sure, you should test it).

But don't hesitate to document it in your code, it's probably the best way.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a define instead of the number? At least it is clearer.

```
#define DERIVED_2 2

typedef Derived<DERIVED_2> Derived_2;
```

But it is not exactly clear what the difference between the derived classes is. Surely they will not be just numbers.